# AWS Glue fails to run the snowflake python connection as in example https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-to-use-aws-glue-with-snowflake/

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting the following thread to assist other Snowflake Users knowing what will work with AWS Glue)

---

I am trying to achieve the snowflake connection in my aws glue job as mentioned in example on :

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-to-use-aws-glue-with-snowflake/

I am using latest versions

- spark-snowflake_2.12-2.5.2-spark_2.4
- snowflake-jdbc-3.9.1
- Glue Version - Spark 2.4, Python 3 (Glue version 1.0)

But getting below error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o75.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Parameters$MergedParameters.<init>(Parameters.scala:208)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Parameters$.mergeParameters(Parameters.scala:202)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer #1:**
Maybe I am a bit generic, but I tend to assume errors like this are due to version incompatibilities. What is your SCALA version? Here's some general information (may need to click 'Expand Post' to see all) that may help getting setup:

I believe AWS Glue now supports Spark 2.4.3, but it's still pretty new and perhaps not as thoroughly tested. You are free to try it, or try Spark 2.2.1 below which we also know AWS Glue supports.

- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/aws-glue-now-supports-ability-to-run-etl-jobs-apache-spark-243-with-python-3/

We know AWS Glue also supports Spark 2.2.1 so I am going to elaborate here instead. The first link is documentation about AWS Glue support for this version and the second link is where you can download this version of the spark-snowflake connector.

- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/04/aws-glue-now-supports-apache-spark-221/
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/spark-snowflake_2.11/2.2.1/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.2.1.jar

For Spark 2.2.1, I believe you need SCALA 2.11 which you can find here:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.snowflake/spark-snowflake

You can use the latest snowflake JDBC driver downloaded here:

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/

Hope this helps. Let us know if you still get the same error.

**Response #2:**
I am able to connect and load the table from snowflake database to dataframe with help of your suggestion.

I am using version,

1) Spark 2.2, Python2, Glue version (0.9)

2) spark-snowflake_2.11-2.2.1.jar

3) snowflake-jdbc-3.2.7

But when I do df.printschema() everything is good but when I do df.show() it gives below error:

I am also not able to save this dataframe to s3 bucket.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o75.showString.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/snowflake/client/jdbc/internal/snowflake/common/core/S3FileEncryptionMaterial
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.ConnectorSFStageManager.encMat$lzycompute(ConnectorSFStageManager.scala:203)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.ConnectorSFStageManager.encMat(ConnectorSFStageManager.scala:201)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.ConnectorSFStageManager.masterKey$lzycompute(ConnectorSFStageManager.scala:231)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.ConnectorSFStageManager.masterKey(ConnectorSFStageManager.scala:230)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRDD.<init>(SnowflakeRDD.scala:60)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.getRDDFromS3(SnowflakeRelation.scala:189)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.buildScanFromSQL(SnowflakeRelation.scala:103)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder.toRDD(QueryBuilder.scala:81)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder.rdd$lzycompute(QueryBuilder.scala:28)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder.rdd(QueryBuilder.scala:28)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder$$anonfun$getRDDFromPlan$1.apply(QueryBuilder.scala:183)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder$$anonfun$getRDDFromPlan$1.apply(QueryBuilder.scala:182)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder$.getRDDFromPlan(QueryBuilder.scala:182)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.SnowflakeStrategy.buildQueryRDD(SnowflakeStrategy.scala:35)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.SnowflakeStrategy.apply(SnowflakeStrategy.scala:20)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:62)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2837)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2363)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:241)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.snowflake.common.core.S3FileEncryptionMaterial
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

**Answer #2**
Can you try again with a later version of the JDBC driver?

**Response #3**
Thank you for looking into it. I was able to resolve the issue with below combination of versions:

```
Spark 2.4, Python 3 (Glue version 1.0)
spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.8.jar
snowflake-jdbc-3.6.12.jar
```

**Answer #3**
Thank you for posting the versions as well so other users know what will work with AWS Glue.